# Change the Subnet address of an App Service Environment

Tags: azure, subnet, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have an App Service Environment (ASE) that is all working as expected. Unfortunately I now need to change to IP address range of the ASE, currently it is set as 10.0.0.0/26 and I'd like it to be 10.0.6.0/26. When I try to configure the Subnet associated with the ASE, I get an error saying I can't change it because it is in use.

Is there any way to change the IP Address range of the ASE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess i'll be the bearer of bad news here. The answer is no. You have to delete the ASE and redeploy it to the new subnet.

From the [docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service/environment/app-service-web-how-to-create-an-app-service-environment.md#creating-an-app-service-environment-v1):

> #### Before you create your ASE
>
> It is important to be aware of the things you cannot change. Those aspects you cannot change about your ASE after it is created are:
>
> - Location
> - Subscription
> - Resource Group
> - VNet used
> - **Subnet used**
> - **Subnet size**

While at it, you probably want to deploy an [ASEv2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-app-service-isolated-more-power-scale-and-ease-of-use/) instead.

Comment: Oh dear, hadn't spotted that. Thanks.